# Character streams often “wrappers” for byte streams

Tags: java

While going through character stream information in java IO Stream, I found following lines hard to understand:

**Character streams often “wrappers” for byte streams. the character stream uses the byte stream to perform the physical I/O, while the character stream handles translation between characters and bytes. FileReader, for example, uses FileInputStream, while FileWriter uses FileOutputStream.**

would someone help me to understand... Thank you

Comment: What part is confusing? In UTF-16 some characters take more than one byte.

Comment: What can you understand so far? The question is too broad to be on-topic on Stack Overflow. Also, please quote the source of the description.

Comment: A character is not the same thing as a byte. Some characters require more than one byte to store. For example: ϱ needs two bytes.

Comment: In UTF-16 all characters require at least two bytes.

Comment: David, here is the source of description: "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html", under the heading "Character Streams that use Byte Streams"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the lowest level a file consists of a byte sequence. The meaning of these bytes depends on the application which is responsible to read and write these bytes. The bytes can be interpreted as a JPEG image, a MP3 sound file or a text.

For a text interpretation you need a mapping between bytes and characters. These mappings are called character encodings. There are many different character encodings out there. For simple character encodings like Windows ANSI (Cp1252) or DOS encoding (Cp437) there is a one to one relationship between bytes and characters. So every character is encoded as exactly one byte.

But there are more complex encodings like UTF-8. The byte sequence for one character may consist of one byte or two or more bytes.

In Java the byte level is handled by the byte stream classes like `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. For character streams (text) there are the subclasses of `Reader` and `Writer`.

The two classes `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` are very important here, because these form the connection between character and byte streams.

An `InputStreamReader` is a `Reader` so you can read characters out of it. But it wraps an `InputStream` a byte stream. Internally it reads the bytes of the wrapped bytes stream and translate these bytes to characters according to a character encoding.

An `OutputStreamWriter` is a `Writer`. You write characters or strings into it. The `OutputStreamWriter` wraps an `OutputStream`. The characters are mapped to bytes with the encoding are written to the `OutputStream`.

If the character encoding isn't specified in the constructor then the platform's default encoding is used (usually Windows-ANSI on Windows and UTF-8 on Linux).

Example: To write the String `Pelé` to the file `name.txt` in UTF-8:

```
try(Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("names.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  writer.write("Pelé");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Usually, you add additional Writers, e.g. for buffering or printing:

```
try(PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("names.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
  writer.println("Pelé");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To be complete, here is the corresponding reading example. Here we use `Files.newBufferedReader()` to create a `FileInputStream` wrapped by a `BufferedReader`:

```
Path namesFile = Paths.get("names.txt");
try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(namesFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```